# How was the Space Shuttles rollover maneuver achieved?

Tags: space-shuttle

Was the roll made using the SSME gimbal control?
I would imagine the SRB does not have this capability.
Is there any use of flight control surfaces as well?

Comment: [Were the aerodynamic control surfaces of the Space Shuttle used during ascent](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/8357/6312) answers the last part.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Attitude control during first stage was achieved by [SRB thrust vector control](http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/shuttle/reference/shutref/srb/thrust.html).  The large distance between the nozzles and the high thrust levels meant that the SRB TVC had enormous control authority.

Bottom line: The roll program was performed by gimballing the SRB nozzles.