# Precisely when did the Shuttle's roll program occur?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle

Previous answers state that the Shuttle launch roll program [occurred as soon as practical after tower clear](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12010/26446) and was [achieved by SRB thrust vector control](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12009/26446).  **Can we get a more precise answer on the conditions that triggered the Shuttle rollover?**

(NASA seems to call it a roll program, even though all three axes are involved.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Single Axis Rotation (SAR) maneuver started when the computed relative velocity of the stack exceeded the value stored in a reconfigurable flight software variable called PPOLY(2).  The nominal value of PPOLY(2) was 118.45 ft/sec. This was nominally achieved at ~ T + 8 seconds and an altitude of ~376 feet.

Source - Ascent Nominal I-Loads Definition and Verification (not online)

There's a great view of it here from an SRB cam and an MET clock in the upper right corner of the video.

See also [What event determined the transfer of control from Kennedy Space Center to Houston?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36211/what-event-determined-the-transfer-of-control-from-kennedy-space-center-to-houst/36219#36219)